# Why doesn't my <select> work in IE8?

Tags: select, internet-explorer-8, drop-down-menu

So I have a `<select>` element on my page, and it worked fine in all browsers until IE8 came along. I've seen all the literature about the IE7 compatibility view and how to use `<meta>` to force the browser into that mode. But the question still remains: why the heck does IE8 fail to display a simple `<select>` properly? Has anyone figured this out yet? Here are two URLs that demonstrate the problem. The first one displays properly in IE8, but only because I'm using the `<meta>` tag to force it into IE7 compatibility mode. The second one is identical to the first, except that I'm not forcing IE7 compatibility.

1. http://www.currensys.com/mhw.php
2. http://www.currensys.com/mhf.php

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Confirm repro on IE8 for the second link. +1

Comment: Thanks so much to Adrian and zowat. You guys just saved me weeks of digging; I would have focused on the HTML for a long time before ever thinking that it might have to do with the CSS. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, IE8 doesn't like one of your CSS styles.

```
SELECT { display: table }
```

Removing the above style displays the drop down list.

**Update**: [more information from W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp), the value of "table" is not supported by IE.

Answer (score 1):

You have a css property setting *display: table* on select elements. This seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ha d the same problem, not solved with the display:table thing, but it was an issue with the font-family...seems that you have to use standard font only (i used fontface for my site...)
so change the font family to a standard one and should be ok(i don't know why but it worked for me)